# Xamarin Android - Optimising code causes App to crash

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

VS 2019 - Xamarin 4.8

In the PCL Project I have the Optimize Code checkbox checked.

In the Android Project, if I check the Optimize Code checkbox, the App crashes immediately on start up.  If I don't have it checked, it works fine.

Question:  Is ticking the Optimize Code checkbox in the Android Project required if it is already ticked in the PCL project?  (to produce optimised code)

I have tried the options from this page:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55666/app-runs-in-debug-mode-crashes-in-release-mode

Comment: I noticed that when I create a Xamarin App from one of the Templates, the Optimize Code checkbox is checked in the Android project.  However, I have no idea how to find out why my code crashes immediately as it does not even reach any of my methods to set a breakpoint?

Comment: Did you run in debug mode or release mode ?

Comment: Release (when the Optimize Code checkbox is ticked in the Build tab of the Android project settings)  Un ticked, the App works fine.

Comment: I just set the Code shrinker from blank to r8 and now it runs.  I'll do more testing tomorrow and create an Answer if all ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the "Code Shrinker" option from blank to r8 seems to have fixed the issue.  In case others are having a similar issue, here are my "Android Options":
[image]

And here are by Android Build settings:
[image]